# How to use the union operator in oracle

Tags: oracle

I know that the union operator is used to (for example) return all rows from two tables after eliminating duplicates. Example:

```
SELECT a_id 
FROM a 
UNION
SELECT b_id
FROM b;
```

The result of listing of all elements in A and B eliminating duplicates is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.
If you joined A and B you would get only {4,5}. You would have to perform a full outer join to get the full list of 1-8. My question is if I wanted to use the union operator to display from a table called employees, the employee_id and job_id ( employee id being a number data type, and job_id being a VARCHAR2 data type) How would I go about doing this?

Would it be something like this: This does not run in oracle obviously,

```
SELECT employee_id
UNION
SELECT job_id
FROM employees;
```

Comment: No.  Union is for two complete select statements.  <select 1> union < select 2> .  I do not understand your question.  Please clarify with some input data, and what your expected results are.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I want to join two sets of data using the union . I figured out that I would use the UNION ALL to do this. My question was very simple. I'm sorry you did not understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to union together all the EMPLOYEE_IDs followed by all the JOB_IDs you'd use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM EMPLOYEES
UNION ALL
SELECT JOB_ID FROM EMPLOYEES
```

If you had rows with EMPLOYEE_IDs of 1, 2, and 3, and those same rows had JOB_IDs of 1, 11, and 111 you'd get a result set of six rows with a single column which would have values of

```
1
2
3
1
11
111
```

By using UNION ALL Oracle will allow the duplicates to pass through.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!! Also, the result will show the salary, if there is no salary how would I substitute a 0 in the column??

Comment: If by "no salary" you mean that the salary column is NULL you could use something like `SELECT NVL(SALARY, 0) FROM EMPLOYEES`, or `SELECT COALESCE(SALARY, HOURLY_RATE*160, 0) FROM EMPLOYEES` if you wanted to potentially substitute an employee's hourly pay rate * 160 nominal hours per month - this is just an example to show that COALESCE is the generalized, multi-valued form of NVL.  Read up on NVL and COALESCE for further information.